# Pandas: Create a dataframe with k columns of n1,n2,n3 etc. random samples

Tags: numpy, pandas

df = DataFrame(randn(10,5))
creates a dataframe which consists of 5 columns with 10 samples in each columns. What would I do if I instead wanted a dataframe with 5 columns, but where the first column contained 10 samples, the second 20 samples, the third 30, etc?

Thank you

Comment: could you write down an example of what you mean? it looks like your table would not be *symmetric*..

Comment: Yes, exactly, it would not be symmetric. So if the last column has 50 values, then the first column will have 40 NaNs, the second 30 NaNs, etc. Ok?

Comment: Can you not create 30 random numbers for all columns and then set back to NaNs the ones you want blank?

Comment: Do you want the numbers (i.e. the non-NaN values) randomly distributed through the available 50 rows?

Comment: @DSM: Yes, RobinL: Yes, but is there a quick way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't overthink this one: just make the random series of the length you want and concatenate them together.  Then permute the results.

```
>>> counts = range(1, 6, 1)
>>> df = pd.concat([pd.Series(np.random.randn(i)) for i in counts],axis=1)
>>> df.apply(np.random.permutation)
          0        1         2         3         4
0       NaN      NaN  1.354730 -0.297923  0.731383
1       NaN      NaN  0.084739       NaN -1.210666
2       NaN  1.55258 -1.016366 -0.294881  0.102921
3       NaN  0.08485       NaN  0.956638 -1.004768
4  0.612248      NaN       NaN  0.167499 -0.419745
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this, I think:

```
>>> import random
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,6))
>>> for i in range(len(df.columns)):
...     df.iloc[random.sample(range(5), i + 1), i] = None
... 
>>> df
           0          1          2          3         4
0  -1.527144 -0.6289867  0.7836826  0.2627288      None
1  0.0391009       None       None       None      None
2 -0.1480286  0.5671133  0.4761757       None      None
3   -1.36673       None       None       None      None
4       None   2.146048       None       None      None
5  -1.019026 -0.8022319 -0.5602172  -1.428174 -1.306279
```